# Which third party tools/library are available for NoSQL databases?

Tags: sql, database, reporting, nosql

I know that NoSQL databases are very new. I am also new in this point. But exist already tools/libraries to make the life easer like for SQL databases?

I think on tools for managing, maintaining, viewing or reporting of the data. There can also be libraries for easer working with the database or an abstract database layer to change the database later.

I would prefer Java libraries but also other are interesting.

Comment: Which database in particular? There is not going to be a one-size-fits-all answer such as JDBC for RDBMS

Comment: The question is database independent. If you know a tool that work only with one NoSQL database then post it.

Comment: If you make your question more specific both in terms of database technology and language choice, I hope you will get some interesting answers. Tools/libraries vary considerably for non-relational databases (e.g. MongoDB, CouchDB, Redis, and so on).

Comment: If you are just interested in gathering information and not have a concrete NoSQL DB in mind, then I suggest -- research your options here http://nosql-database.org/ Decide what databases you will likely to be going along with, then ask specific question mentioning relative ease of use in Java among those DBs.

Comment: If you can't find it, start writing one ;)

Comment: @David James The specific database is not important currently. We think about a switch to a NoSQL DB. But if there are no tools and libraries then we need to write all self. Because the list of answers is very small here we will not switch.

Comment: @Horcrux Re: "Because the list of answers is very small here we will not switch." -> does this mean you are relying on responses here to make your decision? That would be unwise; a lack of responses here is not strong evidence to indicate a lack of NoSQL tools. Frankly, your question is vague and ill-defined; that probably explains why you are not getting answers. (You are asking the community to do a *lot* of work in summarizing what is out there.) Take people's advice: do some research at http://nosql-database.org/ and so on. When your requirements are clearer, come back and ask again.

Comment: @Horcrux7 - "only a list"? I'm not sure what you are expecting. nosql-database.org lists approximately 50+ options to explore. If you want to know what libraries or tools are associated with a particular database, you will need to pick a few databases as candidates for your criteria and then do research. Generally speaking, the heavy hitters (such as MongoDB and Redis just to mention two) have good library support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AllegroGraph, a graph database, certainly fits the description of a No-SQL store. It's [Gruff](http://www.franz.com/agraph/gruff/) tool presents a visual representation of the underlying graph, and has proven itself useful both during development and in production.